How do I get values from the selected row in my table showing my database records?
I am trying to get my name value from my cursor so I can Update and Delete records. When I use the following code I found in an earlier post, I get a "cannot find symbol" error for .getString and "int cannot be dereferenced" on indexForName. I need to pull the name into a variable to use in the next queries.
   if(selectedRow > -1 && selectedRow == row) {
       try {
           int indexForName = cur.getColumnIndex("Name");
       } catch (IOException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }
       String lastname = row.getString(indexForName);
       cell.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xff0000);
       cell.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(100);
   }


This is the right code:
   try {
       int indexForName = cur.getColumnIndex("Name");
       String lastname = row.getString(indexForName);
       cell.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xff0000);
       cell.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(100);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
   }

The variable indexForName was out of the scope denoted by the catch statement.
